# Make plot manually update with Manipulate instead of auto resetting

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

I'm trying to write a script that will dynamically update when I change the tensor that I am working with and the interval tensor elements.

Whenever I update the tensor elements that I am working with in the Dynamic function with the manipulate function, the values are updated, and then it is automatically set to zero again and the plot is reset, as shown in the video [here](https://youtu.be/QSm5f5hn1S4).

Here is the following code

```
Dynamic[Manipulate[Module[{c, \[Epsilon], cx, cy, cz, kin, kout, Epin, Esin, Epout, Esout, Rotx, Roty, Rotz, Rot, chiprime, PxPin, 
     PyPin, PzPin, PxSin, PySin, PzSin, pinpout, pinsout, sinpout, sinsout, Ipinpout, Ipinsout, Isinpout, Isinsout}, 
     
    c = 3*10^8; 
    
    \[Epsilon] = 8.85/10^12; 
    
    {cx, cy, cz} := {0, 0, 1}; 
    
    kin[\[Theta]_] := {-Sin[\[Theta]], 0, -Cos[\[Theta]]}; 
     kout[\[Theta]_] := {Sin[\[Theta]], 0, Cos[\[Theta]]}; 
     Epin[\[Theta]_] := {Cos[\[Theta]], 0, Sin[\[Theta]]}; 
     Esin[\[Theta]_] := {0, 1, 0}; 
     Epout[\[Theta]_] := {Cos[\[Theta]], 0, -Sin[\[Theta]]}; 
     Esout[\[Theta]_] = {0, 1, 0}; 
     Rot[\[Phi]_] := {{Cos[\[Phi]] + cx^2*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]), cx*cy*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]) - cz*Sin[\[Phi]], cx*cz*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]) - cy*Sin[\[Phi]]}, 
       {cx*cy*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]) + cz*Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Phi]] + cy^2*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]), cy*cz*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]) - cx*Sin[\[Phi]]}, 
       {cx*cz*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]) - cy*Sin[\[Phi]], cy*cz*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]]) + cx*Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Phi]] + cz^2*(1 - Cos[\[Phi]])}}; 
       
     chiC1 := {{{xxx, xxy, xxz}, {xxy, xyy, xyz}, {xxz, xyz, xzz}}, {{yxx, yxy, yxz}, {yxy, yyy, yyz}, 
         {yxz, yyz, yzz}}, {{zxx, zxy, zxz}, {zxy, zyy, zyz}, {zxz, zyz, zzz}}}; 
         
     chiprime[\[Phi]_, chi_] := FullSimplify[Transpose[Rot[\[Phi]] . Transpose[Rot[\[Phi]] . (chi . Transpose[Rot[\[Phi]]])]]];
      
     PxPin[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := Sum[chiprime[\[Phi], chi][[1,i]][[j]]*Epin[\[Theta]][[i]]*Epin[\[Theta]][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; 
     PyPin[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := Sum[chiprime[\[Phi], chi][[2,i]][[j]]*Epin[\[Theta]][[i]]*Epin[\[Theta]][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; 
     PzPin[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := Sum[chiprime[\[Phi], chi][[3,i]][[j]]*Epin[\[Theta]][[i]]*Epin[\[Theta]][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; 
     PxSin[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := Sum[chiprime[\[Phi], chi][[1,i]][[j]]*Esin[\[Theta]][[i]]*Esin[\[Theta]][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; 
     PySin[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := Sum[chiprime[\[Phi], chi][[2,i]][[j]]*Esin[\[Theta]][[i]]*Esin[\[Theta]][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; 
     PzSin[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := Sum[chiprime[\[Phi], chi][[3,i]][[j]]*Esin[\[Theta]][[i]]*Esin[\[Theta]][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]; 
     
     pinpout[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := FullSimplify[(PxPin[\[Theta], \[Phi], chi]*Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (PzPin[\[Theta], \[Phi], chi]*Sin[\[Theta]])^2]; 
     
     Ipinpout[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, chi_] := (1/2)*c*\[Epsilon]*pinpout[\[Theta], \[Phi], chi]^2; PolarPlot[Ipinpout[\[Theta], \[Phi], chi], {\[Phi], 0, 2*Pi},
      
      PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Subscript[p, in]*Subscript[p, out]]], 
      
      {chi, {chiC1}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, 
      
   Delimiter,
   
    {{xxx, 0, "xxx"}, -1, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, but removing the `Dynamic` wrapped around the `Manipulate` should prevent the sliders from resetting

Comment: @LukasLang that is what I advised the OP to do in first comment to his other similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271503/plot-automatically-set-to-zero-when-dynamic-function-is-updated) but for some reason they insist in putting Dynamic around Manipulate.

Comment: When I remove Dynamic, the plot does not update when I use the sliders. Do you know of another way to actively change the sliders to update the plot without using Dynamic?

Comment: Does the code work outside of Manipulate?  Before getting to work inside, make sure it works OK outside. Makeup some values to test it outside first. You'll find coding errors much easier outside Manipulate. Once you fix all the errors, then move the code inside Manipulate.

Comment: The code that I am working with is a part longer string of code that I reduced to show the problem easier. The code does work outside of Manipulate but it involves a longer string of code. As such, I am only worried about the auto-resetting of the plot as my problem

Comment: **The code does work outside of Manipulate** It did not work outside for me. I just took the code outside (without the Manipulate stuff) and typed `Ipinpout[\[Theta], \[Phi], chi]` and got lots of errors about Part 2 and Part 3 does not exist?  ALso, I see no theta as input anywhere.  But since I do not understand your code, I can't really be sure what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version:

```
chiC1 = Hold@# -> 
     Map[ToString, #, {3}] &@{{{xxx, xxy, xxz}, {xxy, xyy, 
      xyz}, {xxz, xyz, xzz}}, {{yxx, yxy, yxz}, {yxy, yyy, yyz}, {yxz,
       yyz, yzz}}, {{zxx, zxy, zxz}, {zxy, zyy, zyz}, {zxz, zyz, 
      zzz}}};
chiC1h = Hold@# -> 
     Map[ToString, #, {3}] &@{{{xxx, 0, xxz}, {0, xyy, 0}, {xxz, 0, 
      xzz}}, {{0, yxy, 0}, {yxy, 0, yyz}, {0, yyz, 0}}, {{zxx, 0, 
      zxz}, {0, zyy, 0}, {zxz, 0, zzz}}};
Manipulate[
 Module[{c, ϵ, cx, cy, cz, kin, kout, Epin, Esin, Epout, 
   Esout, Rotx, Roty, Rotz, Rot, chiprime, PxPin, PyPin, PzPin, PxSin,
    PySin, PzSin, pinpout, pinsout, sinpout, sinsout, Ipinpout, 
   Ipinsout, Isinpout, Isinsout}, c = 3*10^8;
  ϵ = 8.85/10^12;
  {cx, cy, cz} := {0, 0, 1};
  kin[θ_] := {-Sin[θ], 0, -Cos[θ]};
  kout[θ_] := {Sin[θ], 0, Cos[θ]};
  Epin[θ_] := {Cos[θ], 0, Sin[θ]};
  Esin[θ_] := {0, 1, 0};
  Epout[θ_] := {Cos[θ], 0, -Sin[θ]};
  Esout[θ_] = {0, 1, 0};
  Rot[ϕ_] := {{Cos[ϕ] + cx^2*(1 - Cos[ϕ]), 
     cx*cy*(1 - Cos[ϕ]) - cz*Sin[ϕ], 
     cx*cz*(1 - Cos[ϕ]) - 
      cy*Sin[ϕ]}, {cx*cy*(1 - Cos[ϕ]) + cz*Sin[ϕ], 
     Cos[ϕ] + cy^2*(1 - Cos[ϕ]), 
     cy*cz*(1 - Cos[ϕ]) - 
      cx*Sin[ϕ]}, {cx*cz*(1 - Cos[ϕ]) - cy*Sin[ϕ], 
     cy*cz*(1 - Cos[ϕ]) + cx*Sin[ϕ], 
     Cos[ϕ] + cz^2*(1 - Cos[ϕ])}};
  chiprime[ϕ_, chi_] := 
   FullSimplify[
    Transpose[
     Rot[ϕ] . 
      Transpose[Rot[ϕ] . (chi . Transpose[Rot[ϕ]])]]];
  PxPin[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   Sum[chiprime[ϕ, chi][[1, i]][[j]]*Epin[θ][[i]]*
     Epin[θ][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  PyPin[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   Sum[chiprime[ϕ, chi][[2, i]][[j]]*Epin[θ][[i]]*
     Epin[θ][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  PzPin[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   Sum[chiprime[ϕ, chi][[3, i]][[j]]*Epin[θ][[i]]*
     Epin[θ][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  PxSin[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   Sum[chiprime[ϕ, chi][[1, i]][[j]]*Esin[θ][[i]]*
     Esin[θ][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  PySin[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   Sum[chiprime[ϕ, chi][[2, i]][[j]]*Esin[θ][[i]]*
     Esin[θ][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  PzSin[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   Sum[chiprime[ϕ, chi][[3, i]][[j]]*Esin[θ][[i]]*
     Esin[θ][[j]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}];
  pinpout[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := 
   FullSimplify[(PxPin[θ, ϕ, chi]*
        Cos[θ])^2 + (PzPin[θ, ϕ, chi]*
        Sin[θ])^2];
  Ipinpout[θ_, ϕ_, chi_] := (1/2)*c*ϵ*
    pinpout[θ, ϕ, chi]^2;
  PolarPlot[
   Evaluate@Ipinpout[θ, ϕ, ReleaseHold@chi], {ϕ, 0, 
    2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> Subscript[p, in]*Subscript[p, out]]
  ],
 {chi, {chiC1,chiC1h}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}, {θ, {0, π/2}},
 Delimiter,
 Evaluate[
  Sequence @@ ({{Symbol@#, 0.1, #}, -1, 1, 0.1, 
       Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ 
     StringJoin @@@ Tuples[{"x", "y", "z"}, {3}])],
 TrackedSymbols :> True
 ]
```

Things I changed:

- I added all the sliders back because otherwise the code doesn't work. For the `xxx` etc. sliders, I use `Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({{Symbol@#, 0.1, #}, -1, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ StringJoin @@@ Tuples[{"x", "y", "z"}, {3}])]` to generate them for me
- I have moved the definition of `chiC1` out of the `Manipulate` body, because it's usually not a good idea to dynamically redefine the possible options for a  `Manipulate` variable like this. I have also used a `value -> label` style specification, so that the thing displayed in the dropdown doesn't change when the variables change. Also, I wrapped the value in `Hold`, such that it is not prematurely evaluated when constructing the controls, but only once inside the body.
- I added the [`TrackedSymbols:>True`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) setting. This ensures that all slider variables cause the body of the `Manipulate` to update, not only those that a literally present (which the `xxx` are not).
- I added `Evaluate` to the expression in `PolarPlot` to make the whole thing a  lot more responsive. This forces the symbolic evaluation (including the `FullSimplify` to run only once, making everything a lot faster. I have also added `ReleaseHold` to remove the `Hold` wrapper around `chi`, now that we are inside the inner `Dynamic`.

Comment: Thank You, is there a way that I can add additional tensors that I can change that have, say with `C1h ={{{xxx, 0, xxz}, {0, xyy, 0}, {xxz, 0, xzz}}, {{0, yxy, 0}, {yxy, 0, yyz}, {0, yyz, 0}}, {{zxx, 0, zxz}, {0, zyy, 0}, {zxz, 0, zzz}}}`

Comment: @Xenconic just add a copy of the first line defining `chiC1` (with the appropriate changes for the new tensor, i.e. change the variable name & tensor entries) and add it to the list of allowed values for `chi` in the manipulate variable spec

Comment: I added the new tensor `chiC1h` with the corresponding tensor above, and added it to the manipulate variable spec, but I encountered the error `Argument 0 at position 1 is expected to be a symbol.`, could you give an example in your code?

Comment: @Xenconic There was indeed a small mistake, sorry. I have updated the answer with a fixed version & added an example of how to add a second tensor. The issue was being caused by the `SymbolName` function that I used to convert the tensor elements to strings (so that they don't depend on the manipulate variable values). Of course that doesn't work for numbers such as `0`. To fix it, I replaced `SymbolName` with `ToString`, which should work in all cases